# SendGrid add multiple email addresses to Recipient Lists in php

Tags: php, sendgrid

I am facing so much of difficulty to adding multiple email addresses to Recipient List.

I am adding one email address to Recipient List successfully, see code here

```
  $email_list = array ( "email" => "srinivas1@addpronetwork.com",'name' => "srinivas");
  $json_email =  json_encode($email_list);

  $url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json';

  $params = array(
    'list'   => urlencode($list_name),
    'data' =>  $json_email,
    'api_user'  => $this->config->item('api_username'),
    'api_key'   => $this->config->item('api_password'),
  );
    $request =  $url;

    // Generate curl request
    $session = curl_init($request);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    // Tell curl to use HTTP POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    // Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
    curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    // Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    // Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
    /*curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);*/
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // obtain response
    $response = curl_exec($session);
    curl_close($session);

    $obj = json_decode($response);
```

In above code I am adding single email address to a list.. my data parameter look like this

```
data => '{ "name": "srinivas", "email": "srinivas@addpronetwork.com" }'
```

When I am trying to add multiple email address but I am facing problem..see data parameter

```
['{"name":"Srinu","email":"srinivas@addpronetwork.com"}','{"name":"Pallavi","email" :"pallavi@addpronetwork.com"}']
```

see this below link

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Marketing_Emails_API/emails.html#-add

Answer (score 0):

You need to add each email entry as its own 'data' variable like this:

```
curl -X POST https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json \
 -d 'api_user=your_sendgrid_username' \
 -d 'api_key=your_sendgrid_password' \
 -d 'list=my_list' \
 -d 'data[]={"email":"address1@domain.com","name":"contactName1"}' \
 -d 'data[]={"email":"address2@domain.com","name":"contactName2"}'
```

In the past i have just looped through my list to add them to my marketing email,  I dont really work in php but this seemed to work:

```
$email_list = array ( '{"name":"Srinu","email":"srinivas@addpronetwork.com"}','{"name":"Pallavi","email" :"pallavi@addpronetwork.com"}');

$url = 'https://api.sendgrid.com/api/newsletter/lists/email/add.json';

foreach ($email_list as &$email) {
 $params = array(
'list'   => "my_list"),
'data[]' =>  $email,
'api_user'  => "api_username",
'api_key'   => "api_password",
);
$request =  $url;

// Generate curl request
$session = curl_init($request);
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

// Tell curl to use HTTP POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POST, true);
// Tell curl that this is the body of the POST
curl_setopt ($session, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
// Tell curl not to return headers, but do return the response
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
// Tell PHP not to use SSLv3 (instead opting for TLS)
/*curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);*/
curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// obtain response
$response = curl_exec($session);
curl_close($session);

$obj = json_decode($response);
print_r($response);
```

Hope that gets you going!